# sql join request

Tags: mysql, sql

Well, i'm trying to make a sql request  with join but i don't know how to do it.

Here my first table - Table 1

- id
- postid
- user

My second table - Table 2

- id
- title

Postid and id are the same.

i've done a screenshot of my table 1
[image]

As you can see, there are many entries with postid 32. This is totally normal.

I want to do a sql request on this 2 tables.
**The results expected have to be like this :**

Title of id 31 (from table 1) - 2 (because there are 2 entries with postid 31 in table 2)

Title of id 32 (from table 1) - 23 (because there are 23 entries with postid 32 in table 2)

Someone can help me ?

Comment: Hi, can you tag a database you use ?

Comment: done. I'm working on mysql

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select t1.postid, count(t2.id)
from Tab1 t1 join Tab2 t2
on t1.postid = t2.id
group by t1.postid;
```

Here the name of the tables are Tab1 and Tab2 and they have aliases t1 and t2.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested only in the `postid`s of `table1` then there is no need for a join:

```
select postid, count(*)
from table1
group by postid;
```

If you want to count all the `id`s of `table2` even the ones that are missing in `table1` then you need a `left join`:

```
select t2.id, count(t1.postid)
from table2 t2 left join table1 t1
on t1.postid = t2.id
group by t2.id;
```